# lsnrctl command not found oracle enterprise database 11g ubuntu

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, listener

i have an issue with the environment variables for oracle 11g enterprise edition on `ubuntu`. I tried this, but didn't work

Add the following lines to /etc/profile:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.X.Y/db_home1        
export PATH=$PATH:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.X.Y/db_home1/bin
```

Add the following environment variables:

```
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle        
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.X.Y/db_home1        
export ORACLE_OWNR=oracle        
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

but the error persist.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it would bother me that `$ORACLE_HOME` isn't set as `$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.X.Y/db_home1`, and `PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

$. oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ?
Enter the Oracle SID and click enter
ORACLE_HOME will be displayed if it is already set, if not you can set it here
$lsnrctl status will now show you the status